# I need to make an Ajax call to get the image source from the server side using ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I need to make an Ajax call to get the image source from the server side using ASP.NET C#.

I got below code example:

```
$('#popup-container').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "img/popup_calculating.gif",
    dataType: "image/gif",
    success: function(img) {
      i = new Image();
      i.src = img;
      $(this).append(i);
    },
    error: function(error, txtStatus) {
    }
  });
});
```

The above code want to implement using ASP.NET C# .aspx pages, but I do not able to understand for implementation, to call images from the server, My requirements are to develop like below.

http://epaper.deccanchronicle.com/epaper_main.aspx#page986808

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET (MVC) Serving images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588333/asp-net-mvc-serving-images)

Comment: Using web forms not MVC. @Gusman

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/image-aspnet

Comment: Please can you update your answer with C# and html Code. @Gusman

Comment: No, I did not add an answer, just pointed to resources with info, what you're asking has been explained literally thousands of times, google for results.

Comment: I need this type of requirements, Pls update your answer http://epaper.deccanchronicle.com/epaper_main.aspx#page986808  . @Gusman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104859/discussion-between-zahed-and-gusman).

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you need AJAX call? Why can't you create new Image(), set its SRC to appropriate URL and append it to #popup-container.

Comment: Ok can you answer what code I have use for above requirements. @VivekAthalye

Answer (score 1):

Well for a start, $(this) is not what you think it is because it's contained within a different scope (the success callback of the $.ajax request).

```
$('#popup-container').click(function() {
var container = $(this);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "img/popup_calculating.gif",
    dataType: "image/gif",
    success: function(imgSrc) {
      $(container).append('<img src="' + imgSrc + '" />);
    },
    error: function(error, txtStatus) {

    }
});
```

});

Comment: I have to call from my image folder or what?. Please can you update your full code according to my requirement. @John Mc